Power BI DAX - How Can I use Case Switch instead of IFs
I would like to know how can I change this DAX Code, to use Case Switch instead of IFs
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "AERIAL DUELS WON %", format(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##%"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "CROSSES",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "Crossing%",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##%"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "FORWARD PASSES %",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##%"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "FOULS COMMITTED",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "GOALS",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "GOALS CONCEDED",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "GROUND DUELS WON %",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##%"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "NON-PENALTY SHOT CONVERSION RATE %",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##%"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "NON-PENALTY SHOTS",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "OWN HALF BALL LOSS",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "PASS FORWARD IN FINAL 3RD %",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##%"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "PASSES",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "POSSESSION REGAINS IN OPPO HALF TOTAL",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "Possession%",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##%"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "RED CARDS",IF(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]) \>0, FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),0),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "SHOTS INSIDE BOX",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "SHOTS ON TARGET %",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##%"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "SHOTS OUTSIDE BOX",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "Successful Box Cross",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##"),
IF(VALUES(Rankings\[Attribute\]) = "YELLOW CARDS",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings\[Value\]),"##")
)))))))))))))))))))))`

I need to change the format to use CASE SWITCH

While the other answers work, SWITCH uses the initial value as the comparison, so you don't have to repeat it for each value:
SWITCH(VALUES(Rankings[Attribute])
        , "AERIAL DUELS WON %", format(SUM(Rankings[Value]),"##%")
        , "CROSSES",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]),"##")
        , ...
        )

The TRUE is usually used when the expressions use different fields.
See MS Docs - SWITCH for more details.

You can use this pattern:
SWITCH(TRUE()
, Condition1, Output1
, Condition2, Output2
, Condition3, Output3
, Default
)

Example:
SWITCH(TRUE()
, VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "AERIAL DUELS WON %", format(SUM(Rankings[Value]),"##%")
, VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "CROSSES",FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]),"##")
, ...
)


You can apply the below approach.Set some default value too,i used blank as of now.
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "AERIAL DUELS WON %", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##%"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "CROSSES", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "Crossing%", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##%"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "FORWARD PASSES %", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##%"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "FOULS COMMITTED", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "GOALS", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "GOALS CONCEDED", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "GROUND DUELS WON %", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##%"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "NON-PENALTY SHOT CONVERSION RATE %", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##%"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "NON-PENALTY SHOTS", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "OWN HALF BALL LOSS", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "PASS FORWARD IN FINAL 3RD %", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##%"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "PASSES", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "POSSESSION REGAINS IN OPPO HALF TOTAL", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "Possession%", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##%"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "RED CARDS", IF(SUM(Rankings[Value]) > 0, FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"), 0),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "SHOTS INSIDE BOX", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "SHOTS ON TARGET %", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##%"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "SHOTS OUTSIDE BOX", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "Successful Box Cross", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    VALUES(Rankings[Attribute]) = "YELLOW CARDS", FORMAT(SUM(Rankings[Value]), "##"),
    BLANK()  -- Default  for nothing matching 
)

